# NavBar not displaying

Tags: html, css, particles.js

I used this particle js but after then i am making one resposive nav bar but its showing up . But when i am trying to display only the navbar then it is working . I am basically trying to have a fully responsive sticky top navigation bar with this particle js as background and then with those buttons in navbar it will link to other pages.

KIndly help me in this error:
My HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Particles Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top"  style="background-color: #e3f2fd;" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="
            navbarResponsive">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Instructors</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Founders</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <form class="newsletter">
                        <input type="email" name="newslettertext" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe">
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



    <div id="particles-js">
        <div class="btext">
            <h1>Code Yard</h1>
            <p>Live to Code Another Day</p>
            <a href="index.html" class="btn">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json',
        function(){
            console.log('particles.json loaded...')
        })
    </script>





</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS file is:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.btext{
    color: #f9f3f4;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 0.4em;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50px;
}

.btn{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    line-height: 4em;
}

.btn:hover{
    color: #b19295;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
}

#particles-js{
    background-image: url('image1.jpg');
    height: 100vh;
}
```

My JSON file for particles:

```
    "particles":{
        "number":{
            "value":80
        },
        "color":{
            "value":"#f9f3f4"
        },
        "shape":{
            "type":"circle",
            "stroke":{
                "width":1,
                "color":"#ccc"
            }
        },
        "opacity":{
            "value":0.5,
            "random":true
        },
        "size":{
            "value":2
        },
        "line_linked":{
            "enable":true,
            "distance":110
        },
        "move":{
            "enable":true,
            "speed": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code
`<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">`

Change it to

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
```

It will work
You need to change class="navbar-toggler" to class="navbar-toggle"

Comment: Add a short explanation to what you changed and what it does.

Comment: You need to change class="navbar-toggler" to class="navbar-toggle"

Answer (score 0):

you have used `class="navbar-toggler"` which should be `class="navbar-toggle"` on the `button` element